# Dynamically added inputs to form have no value

Tags: jquery, dynamic, thymeleaf, form-fields

I am adding some input fields to my form dynamically, and when I submit the form the value of the newly added fields are null.

I've already tried to use serialize() on the form after adding the fields, but no success.

Code after which I am adding

```html
<div class="row original " id="control-group-1">
    <div class="col-8 pr-0 ">
        <input class="form-control" name="formDates" type="text" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 pl-0">
        <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button" data-target="#control-group-1">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code which I am copying

```html
<div class="copy d-none">
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="col-8 pr-0 ">
            <input class="form-control" name="formDates" type="text"
                   placeholder="Date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 pl-0">
            <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Remove
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I am copying it.

```
    $(function() {
       $(".add-more").click(function(){
           var html = $(".copy").html();
           var target = $(this).data('target');
           $(target).after(html);
       });


       $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
           $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
       });
    });
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".add-more").click(function() {
    var html = $(".copy").html();
    var target = ".original";
    $(target).after(html);
    var some = $('form').serialize();
    console.log(some);
  });


  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
     var some = $('form').serialize();
    console.log(some);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form role="form" class="form" th:action="@{'/course/course/newOccurrence/' + ${course.idCourse}}" method="POST" th:object="${newOccurrence}">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="idVenue" th:value="${av.value.idVenue}" />
    <div class="col">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{teacherName}" placeholder="Teacher">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row original " th:id="${'control-group-' + iterStat.index}">
        <div class="col-8 pr-0 ">
          <input class="form-control" name="formDates" type="text" placeholder="Date">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 pl-0">
          <button class="btn btn-success add-more" th:attr="data-target='#control-group-' + ${iterStat.index}" type="button">
                                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add
                                                        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="copy d-none">
        <div class="row control-group">
          <div class="col-8 pr-0 ">
            <input class="form-control" name="formDates" type="text" placeholder="Date">
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 pl-0">
            <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i
                                                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Remove
                                                            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col"><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{time}" placeholder="Time"></div>
    <div class="col"><input class="form-control" type="text" th:field="*{active}" placeholder="Active"></div>
    <div class="col-md-auto"><input class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" type="submit"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm assuming that I am missing some step into binding the inputs to the forms, however in my request I clearly see that I have N objects, but ones that are generated dynamically have no value.
I'm wondering if there is a solution to this other than using jquery to send a post request ? I am also using Thymeleaf.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example (in an SO snippet)?   Specifically - where is your `<form>`?  Where do you remove `.d-none`?  Where do you change the `name` attribute?  this last one is probably the issue, but depends on:  how are you serialising the form?

Comment: Hi @freedomn-m, I've added a snippet. In the snippet the serialization works but it doesn't when I debug my application, might it have to do with Thymeleaf ? I'm using the same name "formDates" for all fields, I'm mapping it to a list of strings in my backend, this works if I manually add multiple fields, the only fields that do not work are the ones which I add dynamically. I don't remove .d-none, because I am copying the value of that div.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've provided.  Adding inputs  with the same name (and then putting values in via the UI) and then calling `.serliaze()` serialises those inputs just fine.  https://jsfiddle.net/u94thjw0/  How are you asserting that it's not working?

Comment: Yes - forget about d-none, that's the wrapper.

Comment: Could be something to do with your framework.  Not my area, sorry.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Well I'm doing the same thing while running the application and logging to the console in the browser, it just picks up the existence of the fields but the values are empty. I think because the form is processed server-side then it has problems like this. It might be something from Thymeleaf. Thanks anyway :) !

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `[]` to the name of the input since they all have the same name you will be able to get only the first value when you submit.
Or if you are using jQuery ajax and not normal submit you can store the values in an array and send it like so :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".add-more").click(function() {
    var html = $(".copy").html();
    var target = $(this).data('target');
    $(target).after(html);
  });


  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });
});

$('#submitButton').on('click', function() {
  var formDates = [];
  $('[name="formDates[]"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() !== ''){
      formDates.push($(this).val());
    }
  });
  console.log(formDates);
  // Send the ajax request here ..
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row original " id="control-group-1">
  <div class="col-8 pr-0 ">
    <input class="form-control" name="formDates[]" type="text" placeholder="Date">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2 pl-0">
    <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button" data-target="#control-group-1">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add
        </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="copy d-none">
  <div class="row control-group">
    <div class="col-8 pr-0 ">
      <input class="form-control" name="formDates[]" type="text" placeholder="Date">
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 pl-0">
      <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Remove
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-12 text-center" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="btn" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer, it certainly helps if I want to use JQuery, but I'm trying to avoid it, I might have no choice but to use it thought. Also you can use the same name for the field, because in the request I process it as a list in my backend.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to implement this using Thymeleaf, I've used their [dynamic fieldsfeature](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields) I believe the issue was created by the fact that the form was generated server side. Thanks everyone for answering !